# Import ArcGIS Esri_style to QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I want to add esri_styles (ArcGIS) to QGIS. I went through the web but I haven't found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

SLYR (https://north-road.com/slyr/) is one tool which does this task.

> The SLYR plugin offers rich integration within the QGIS application,
>   by adding common functionality like support for direct drag and drop
>   of the ESRI style and LYR formats to the QGIS application window.

Comment: However, it is not free....

Comment: It's not free *yet*. You have three options: 1. Buy the very expensive SLYR tool; 2. Wait for SLYR to be free, which will happen after enough other people buy it; or 3. Do it yourself (manually re-create the ESRI styles in QGIS). Before North Road came out with SLYR, option 3 was the only option. Once the SLYR tool becomes free, it will be a huge advance over the situation that existed previously. If you feel impatient, I recommend looking up the price of ArcGIS, to remind yourself how great it is that QGIS exists at all.